# How do I program a dimension that captures a logged-in user in WordPress with Google Analytics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

My problem is this: I'd like to differentiate Google Analytics between logged in WordPress users (people editing the site, editors) and people visiting the site (visitors).

I read through this article: https://css-tricks.com/learning-use-google-analytics-effectively-codepen/

It provides a basic explanation of how to add a dimension to GA. What I don't get is how to make line of code to add to my WordPress templates that will tell Google which users are logged in and which ones aren't.

*If you can help, thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to populate the datalayer of your website with a boolean value (true or false) that determines whether someone is logged in or not. You can ask one of your devs to do this, but since you're using Wordpress [there are quite some plugins](https://gtm4wp.com/how-to-articles/what-is-in-the-datalayer-when-using-this-wordpress-plugin/data-about-the-logged-in-user-on-the-site) that are able to do this (make sure you check the safety of these plugins).

After you've done that, you can now actually target these datalayer values in Google Tag Manager and create a custom dimension that you can in turn use for your filters and/or segments in Google Analytics. [This guy](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Filters/How-to-track-logged-in-users-using-Google-Tag-Manager/td-p/880938) explains it quite well on how to do this step by step.